# Aggregate in MongoDB return more fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm currently experimenting with MongoDB. Using the Twitters Streaming API I collected a bunch of tweets (seemed a good way to learn to use MongoDB's aggregation options).

I have the following query

```
db.twitter.aggregate([
    { $group : { _id : '$status.user.screen_name', count: { $sum : 1 } } },
    { $sort : { count : -1, _id : 1 } },
    { $skip : 0 },
    { $limit : 5 },
]);
```

As expected this is te result:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "VacaturesBreda",
            "count" : 5
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "breda_nws",
            "count" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "BredaDichtbij",
            "count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "JobbirdUTITBaan",
            "count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "vacatures_nr1",
            "count" : 2
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

The question is how can I match on the user `id_str` and return the `screen_name` and for example the `followers_count` of the user. I tried to do this with `{ $project .... }` but I kept ending up with an empty result set.

For those not familiar with the user object in Twitters JSON response here a part of it (just selected the first user in the db).

```
"user" : {
        "id" : 2678963916,
        "id_str" : "2678963916",
        "name" : "JobbirdUT IT Banen",
        "screen_name" : "JobbirdUTITBaan",
        "location" : "Utrecht",
        "url" : "http://www.jobbird.com",
        "description" : "Blijf op de hoogte van de nieuwste IT/Automatisering vacatures in Utrecht, via http://Jobbird.com",
        "protected" : false,
        "verified" : false,
        "followers_count" : 1,
        "friends_count" : 1,
        "listed_count" : 0,
        "favourites_count" : 0,
        "statuses_count" : 311,
        "created_at" : "Fri Jul 25 07:35:48 +0000 2014",
        ...
    },
```

*Update:* As requested a clear example on the proposed response (sorry for not adding it).

So instead of grouping on the `screen_name` grouping on the `id_str`. Why you might ask, it is possible to edit your `screen_name` but you are still the same user for Twitter (so the last `screen_name` should be returned:

```
db.twitter.aggregate([
    { $group : { _id : '$status.user.id_str', count: { $sum : 1 } } },
    { $sort : { count : -1, _id : 1 } },
    { $skip : 0 },
    { $limit : 5 },
]);
```

And as the response something like this:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "123456789",
            "screen_name": "awsome_screen_name",
            "followers_count": 523,
            "count" : 5
        }, 
        ....
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Could a add a clearer example of what you expect as a response?

Comment: @NeilLunn sorry, I added it now, thought I had been clear enough, but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically looking for an operator that does not specifically "aggregate" the content, and this is basically what the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) and [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) operators do:

```js
db.twitter.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$status.user.id_str",
        "screen_name": { "$first": "$status.user.screen_name" },
        "followers_count": { "$sum": "$status.user.followers_count" },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "followers_count": -1, "count": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 5 }
])
```

Which picks the "first" occurrence of the field based on the grouping key. That is generally useful where there is duplicated related data in the documents to the grouping key.

An alternate approach is to include the fields in the grouping key. You can later restructure with **`$project`**:

```js
db.twitter.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
            "_id": "$status.user.id_str",
             "screen_name": "$status.user.screen_name"
        },
        "followers_count": { "$sum": "$status.user.followers_count" },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "screen_name": "$_id.screen_name"
        "followers_count": 1,
        "count": 1
    }},
    { "$sort": { "followers_count": -1, "count": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 5 }
])
```

Which is useful where you are unsure of the related "uniqueness".

Comment: Thanks, that worked. A question though, I was under the impression that the grouping of the data would happen on all the fields in the group section, but am I correct to say that it only groups on the `_id` field?

Comment: @MThomas I actually added another approach to this. Yes the `_id` field is the "grouping key", everything outside of this requires a ["grouping accumulator operator"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/). Best to look at all of the aggregation operators in the documentation to gain an understanding.

Comment: thanks. A final question on those operators, I was under the assumption that a `$sum` will add up all values of that field, (as it does in the count), but why is that not the case for the `followers_count`. I would have used `$first`.

Comment: @MThomas What do you mean? "followers_count" is a number so you either want to add it up or use and operator like `$first`. So it depends on what you want to do. The "example" here is showing that the "value" of the field can be passed to `$sum` rather than just a hard number like 1. It is difficult for people to understand your exact requirements unless you explain them clearly.

Comment: again sorry for the lack of clearness. The followers count is a value set by twitter, not by me, and it is present in all documents, so adding it up seemed weird to me. But I do get the use of the operators now more clearly, honestly thanks for your help!